# Specify min-width in a flexbox layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I have the following layout which is based on Bootstrap's Flexbox:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <section class="left"></section>
  <section class="center"></section>
  <section class="right"></section>
</div>
```

And the CSS of this:

```
.left {
    flex: 0 0 360px;
}

.right {
    flex: 0 0 400px;
}

.center { 
    flex: 1; 
}
```

So, with this layout I have 2 left and right columns which have fixed width and a fluid center column. I'm wondering if there's a way to specify a min-width to the center container so it gets a horizontal scrollbar when the the min-width is reached because of small browser width.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `min-width` in a flex item to define the minimum width `flex-shrink` will apply. With `overflow-x` you define how is their behavior when a child node overflows its content width.

#### EDIT #1

As stated by [Michael_B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3597276/michael-b), you can use a built-in flexbox solution making `min-width` unnecessary. The solution is to set `flex-grow: 1;`, `flex-shrink: 0;` and `flex-basis: 100px; /* Or any value you want */`. The short hand for this 3 properties is `flex: 1 0 100px;`.

```css
section {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 360px;
}

.right {
  flex: 0 0 400px;
}

.center { 
    flex: 1 0 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <section class="left">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </section>
  <section class="center">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </section>
  <section class="right">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not be consistent with the other rules and set `.center` to `flex: 1 0 100px`? No need for `min-width`.

Comment: You're right, my bad! I will update the answer, thank you! ;)

Comment: Your answer wasn't wrong (I already +1). Just suggesting a bit of consolidation and improved efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following style properties to the `.center` element:

```
.center { 
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    min-width: 100px; /* Set value to whatever you want */
    overflow: auto; 
}
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-cu7gps?file=index.html)